# Where to put a class that is not a controller, module or view?

Tags: class, logging, module, zend-framework2, autoload

I have a ZF2 application made of several modules, and I want to create a `Logger` class that should be accessible from any of these modules. Basically, I want to be able to log from anywhere with a simple `Logger::info("Something")`.

The current application layout is like this:

```
root/
  module/
    module1/
      src/
        module2/
          src/
        module3/
          src/
```

Where would be the best place to put this new logger class? And how to make sure it is accessible from any of the sub-modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put general classes that should be acceible by all under module/Application/src/WhateverName

For example, I put the auth class under:

```
module/Application/src/Application/Authentication/AuthenticationService.php
```

With the namespace:

```
namespace Application\Authentication;
```

And then I define the service in the Module.php

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'auth_service' => function ($sm) {
                $zfauthservice = new \Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;
                return new \Application\Authentication\AuthenticationService($zfauthservice, $sm->get('bp_user_mapper_model'));
            },
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `ServiceManager` rather than calling a static method, this will allow you to more easily swap out the logging class if needed going forward.

Also ZF2 modules are quite flexible in terms of how code can be structured, so you could simply use:

```
module/Application/src/Application/Logger/LoggerFactory.php
```

Or perhaps create a Logger module if you see this code being reused in other projects.

I did see a blog post from Rob Allen yesterday regarding directory structure of modules - http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/thoughts-on-module-directory-structure/ - it may be worth having a quick read.